# searching for number in text file and modify it in for loop

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I have a text file called txtfile.txt and it has inside it for example the following:

```
x=0
y=0
z=10
```

I want to run a for loop from -x to +x with steps of y to search for z and add the number (x) to it.
( I just want to change the number 
How can I do this?that it follows "z=" and nothing more. It is in a text file and I want to change that in the txt file without anything else

thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with the results? Output the different values of the result?

Comment: I want it the result to be as line but the number changes like if we take an example loop from -2 to 2 with step 1 the answer I want to get 
z = 8
z = 9
z = 10
z = 11 
z = 12
I want it to modify it in the text file

Answer (score 0):

Include this file to your script and then in script you will have variables $x, $y and $z

Answer (score 0):

You may include this line in your Batch program:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in (txtfile.txt) do set %%a
```

After this line the variables defined in the txtfile.txt have their values assigned.

About the second part of your request, I don't understand what "to search for z and add the number (x) to it" means. Where do you want to "search for z"? Who is "it"? Please, modify your question in order to include an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set myfile=txtfile.txt
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims== " %%a in (%myfile%) do ( 
  if %%a EQU x set start=%%b
  if %%a EQU y set step=%%b
  if %%a EQU z set find=%%b
)

for /l %%f in (-!start!, !step!, !start!)  do (
  if %%f EQU !start! (
   set /a new=!find!+!start!
   call :FindRepl !find! !new! %myfile%
  ) 
)
exit /b


:FindRepl
::Adapted from DosTips batch file::
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X>>%temp%\_.tmp
    ) ELSE echo.
)
Move /y %temp%\_.tmp "%3">nul
exit /b
```